# When must I use and verify nonce?

Tags: php, security, nonce

I'm developing a WordPress site which posts a number of ajax calls from jquery to PHP and returns data from PHP to jquery.

I need to know when must I use and verify nonce?

Answer (score 4):

Nonces should be used to verify *intent* of the user, especially on destructive actions.

Imagine there is a link user can click to delete a post. User *can* do it, so when they click is a post gets deleted.

Now imagine someone else *tricks* user into clicking this link (*look at this cat pic!*). User still *can* do it, so from access perspective they are allowed to and a post still gets deleted. But it wasn't their *intent* to delete anything in this situation.

Nonce adds a level of protection into these situations by limiting the action to a specific user in a specific span of time. If nonce is used then that very specific nonce needs to be used to trick user into taking an action.

Answer (score 2):

You would use a nonce to help verify that the request came from a page generated by your website.

If you verify a nonce that comes with an AJAX request, then there's a pretty good chance that the request came from your site's front-end, where `wp_create_nonce()` was run, rather than a bot, 3rd-party application, or malicious script sending a request to your admin-ajax.php file.

Take note of this message from [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) however (emphasis mine):

> They help protect against several types of attacks including CSRF, but
>   do not protect against replay attacks because they aren't checked for
>   one-time use. Nonces should never be relied on for authentication or
>   authorization, access control. Protect your functions using
>   current_user_can(), **always assume Nonces can be compromised**.

So they're far from the only thing you should use to secure your requests, but they can provide an extra layer for certain types of attacks.